# Fragment Interactions

Tags: android

I am trying to add a fragment to an existing layout from within the onClick method of a button in another Fragment class..

In my MainActivity I add two fragments to the layout..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Collapsebutton_Fragment cbut_frag;
private ColourView_Fragment cvw_frag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cbut_frag = new Collapsebutton_Fragment();
    cvw_frag = new ColourView_Fragment();

    //ColourView Fragment ready
    //CollapseButton Fragment ready

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container_mainactivity, cbut_frag)
            .add(R.id.container_mainactivity, cvw_frag)
            .commit();
}
}
```

One of the added fragments contains a button. When clicking that button - accessing the onClick method of the button - I want to add another fragment..

My code is the following:

```
public class ColourView_Fragment extends Fragment {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;
ThreeButton_Fragment tbt_fragment;
public ColourView_Fragment(){}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.colourview_fragment, container, false);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ColourView);

    frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .add(R.id.container_mainactivity, tbt_fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

I get the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

There is an error in line

```
.add(R.id.container_mainactivity, tbt_fragment)
```

How can I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized `tbt_fragment` in `ColourView_Fragment`